# VB.net Hold down the Ctrl Key while Space is pressed

Tags: vb.net

Hello first time poster I'm having issues finding code that will hold down the Ctrl key while Space is being pressed. I have been all over the place and have not been able to find any examples that will help me the way I need. Here's some topics I've checked:

http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbforums/Topic25861-5-1.aspx

http://www.mpgh.net/forum/33-visual-basic-programming/391580-vb-hold-key-down.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally questions should contain some evidence of [what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - code samples are perfect for this. Some context also helps: what are you trying to accomplish? Check out our new [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for guidance on how to use the site (you get a badge if you scroll all the way to the bottom!).

Comment: You might be interested in http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, only a *user* can actually hold down a key.  However, you can simulate the effect of holding down a control key.  The Windows API has the function `SendInput()`  which you can call from VB.Net to accomplish what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx